# How to use PadeApproximant with a defined Derivative?

Tags: pattern-matching, series-expansion

I need to generate a Pade approximant expansion in `v` of the following:

$$g(x,v)\equiv \ln\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y\left(z\right)}N\left(x-z,v\right)\,\mathrm{d}z
 $$

where $y(x)\equiv\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}x^{i}$, $n$ is even, and $c_{n}>0$ so the integral converges. $N(x,v)$ is the PDF of the Normal distribution in $x$ with variance $v$.  I can generate derivatives of $g[x,v]$ wrt $v$ using the following relations, which arise from properties of the Normal:

$$\frac{dg[x,v]}{dv}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^{2}g}{dx^{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dg}{dx}\right)^{2}$$

$$g[x,0]=y(x)$$

This code implements the above relations:

```
ord = 5;
Derivative[q_, 1][g][x_, v_] = 
   D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}]/2;
h = Table[D[g[x, v], {v, i}], {i, 0, ord - 1}];
y[x_] := Sum[c[i]*x^i, {i, 0, 4}];
dgdv = 
  Expand[h /. Derivative[q_, 0][g][x, v] -> D[y[x], {x, q}] /. g[x, v] -> y[x]]
```

But Series doesn't work:

```
Series[g[x, v], {v, 0, 2}]
```

$\qquad g(x,0)+v g^{(0,1)}(x,0)+\frac{1}{2} v^2 g^{(0,2)}(x,0)+O\left(v^3\right)$

and I couldn't figure out how to get pattern matching to complete the result:

```
Series[g[x, v], {v, 0, 2}] /. 
  Derivative[q_, r_][g][x, v] -> 
    D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}, {v, r - 1}]/2
```

gives the same result as the foregoing.

I can cope with `Series` not working because that's easy to hack around, but what I really want to generate is the Pade approximant of `g[x, v]` in `v`, but that's more complicated to hack around.

I realize I could just take the PadeApproximant of a Taylor series generated with my hack code, but that doesn't sound look good practice.

Any ideas?

#### Edit

I think `Series` or `PadeApproximant` might work if I could create a definition of the derivative that works on 2nd derivative wrt v and higher.  It's not an issue in my code above because *Mathematica* seems to just be applying my 1st derivative definition repeatedly.  But `Series` doesn't seem to know to do that, and I can't figure out how to define the derivative w.r.t higher orders of `v` without causing a recursion problem.  I'm posting that as a separate [Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96833/how-to-bound-a-recursive-derivative-definition)

Comment: Your pattern is incomplete. Use `Derivative[q_, 1][g][x_, v_] := 
  D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}]/2;` and it works. Note the change to `SetDelayed`, too, as it generally is what you want, but it makes no difference here.

Comment: @rcollyer  No, doesn't fix the problem.  Series still fails.

Comment: I get `SeriesData[v, 0, {
g[x, 0], Rational[1, 2] (
   Derivative[1, 0][g][x, 0]^2 + Derivative[2, 0][g][x, 0]), 
  Rational[1, 2] Derivative[0, 2][g][x, 0]}, 0, 3, 1]` what do you get?

Comment: I just get the series left in terms of derivs wrt v.  The result I want would be in terms of x and the c[i] coefficients.  I can't make any sense of the result you got, but it's definitely not the answer.

Comment: plug that into mma and hit return.  Barring that, using `Normal` on the `SeriesData` gives `g[x, 0] + (1/2)*v^2*Derivative[0, 2][g][x, 0] + 
  (1/2)*v*(Derivative[1, 0][g][x, 0]^2 + Derivative[2, 0][g][x, 0])` which means it did use the `Derivative` you specified.

Comment: @rcollyer  It only works on the first term of the expansion, then it leaves the $v^2$ term in terms of the 2nd deriv of g wrt v.  That's not useful.  My hack code turn all the the v-derivs into x-derivs.  And anyway, it's the PadeApproximant I need to work.

Comment: @rcollyer  Try completing the calculating with the g->y substitution, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Again, your pattern is incorrect. You specify `g[x,v]` which will match exactly. You want `g[x_,v_] :> y[x]`. Now, that _only_ matches the 0$^{th}$ derivative out front, if you want to match a derivative term, you will need to create a pattern that has `Derivative` in it. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @rcollyer  I changed that already, it doesn't fix the problem.  I appreciate your spending time on this, but you keep posting untested solutions that don't fix the problem.  I need to know how to get the PadeApproximant to work, with the answer entirely in terms of v and the c[i] coefficients.  That is my question.

Comment: It wasn't until your last update, that the problem became clear. It's not a `Derivative` problem, itself, but it is still mostly a pattern problem, albeit a more interesting one now.

Comment: And, you don't need the second question, that's easily addressable here.

Comment: @rcollyer  I posted the 2nd question because we don't know for certain that explicitly defining higher derivs wrt v in the Pattern Matching is the best solution.  I'm sure it would work, but it will be extremely slow if, for example, it calculates the 10th deriv wrt v from scratch instead of starting from the 9th deriv that it already calculated.

Comment: Well, that's a possibility. But, until you know its slow, do the easy thing. I'll post the easy thing in a moment.  Oh, and just a point of note, I was posting _incomplete_ solutions, not untested ones as it seemed a straightforward issue, so I wanted to give you enough to fix it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, this should work

```
Derivative[q_, 1][g][x_, v_] := 
 D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}]/2;
Derivative[q_, n_][g][x_, v_] := 
 D[D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}]/2, {v, n - 1}]
```

But, as we both discovered, it generates recursion errors when fed

```
Derivative[0, #][g][x, 0] & /@ Range[5]
```

So, we need to limit the one pattern, e.g.

```
Derivative[q_, n_?Positive][g][x_, v_] := ...
```

But, doing that we discover another issue: `v` is set to a value, so that

```
Derivative[1, 2][g][x, 0]
```

generates a `General::ivar` message stating `0` is not a variable. This takes a little more work,

```
Derivative[q_, n_?Positive][g][x_, v_] :=
Block[{a, b, res},
 res = D[(D[g[a, b], {a, 2}] + D[g[a, b], a]^2), {b, n - 1}, {a, q}];
 {a, b} = {x, v};
 res
]
```

to replace both patterns. But, for some reason, this does not want to apply the derivative recursively, so we can force it to

```
Derivative[0, 2][g][x, 0] //. 
Derivative[q_, n_?Positive][g][x_, v_] :>
 Block[{a, b, res},
  res = D[(D[g[a, b], {a, 2}] + D[g[a, b], a]^2), {b, n - 1}, {a, q}];
  {a, b} = {x, v};
  res
 ]
(*
2*Derivative[2, 0][g][x, 0]^2 
+ 2*Derivative[1, 0][g][x, 0]*Derivative[3, 0][g][x, 0] 
+ 2*Derivative[1, 0][g][x, 0]*(2*Derivative[1, 0][g][x, 0]*Derivative[2, 0][g][x, 0] 
+ Derivative[3, 0][g][x, 0]) + Derivative[4, 0][g][x, 0]
*)
```

I'll post more later.

Comment: Here's part of the mystery:   http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96853/strange-failure-of-series-and-derivative