# How to bound a recursive Derivative definition?

Tags: pattern-matching, series-expansion

I need to convert derivatives of g[x,v] wrt v into derivatives wrt x using this relation:

$$\frac{dg[x,v]}{dv}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^{2}g}{dx^{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dg}{dx}\right)^{2}$$

This code converts the 0-4th derivatives perfectly:

```
ord = 5;
Derivative[q_, 1][g][x, v] = D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}]/2;
dgdv = Table[D[g[x, v], {v, i}], {i, 0, ord - 1}];
```

Notice that I only defined the 1st deriv of g wrt v, but MMa was smart enough to just apply the relation repeated.  However, Series[] doesn't figure that out, for example it just leaves the 2nd derivative wrt v in that form:

```
Series[g[x, v], {v, 0, 2}]
```

$g(x,0)+v g^{(0,1)}(x,0)+\frac{1}{2} v^2 g^{(0,2)}(x,0)+O\left(v^3\right)$

I attempted to fix my definition to cover higher derivatives wrt v explicitly, but then I ran into recursion problems, which I tried and failed to fix as follows:

```
Derivative[q_, Except[0, n_]][g][x, v] = D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}, {v, n - 1}]/2;
```

This also failed:

```
Derivative[q_, 0][g][x_, v_] := D[g[x, v], {x, q}];
Derivative[q_, r_][g][x_, v_] :=
  If[r > 1,
   D[D[g[x, v], {x, q}, {v, r - 1}], v],
   D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}]/2];
```

I know that's an ugly solution, but I don't know why it didn't work.  Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Derivative[m_, Except[0, n_]][g][x_, v_] := 
   1/2 Derivative[2 + m, n - 1][g][x, v] + 
   1/2 Sum[Binomial[n - 1, k] Binomial[m, j] *
      Derivative[m - j + 1, n - 1 - k][g][x, v] *
      Derivative[j + 1, k][g][x, v], {k, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, m}]
```

`Series[g[x, v], {v, 0, 2}]` now gives the expected output.

Comment: Yes, that totally worked.  I see what you did there, manually coding out the Binomial expansion for the derivs of $g'^2$.  But that seems like something MMa should have been able to do itself.  Why didn't my version work?

Comment: @JerryGuern I don't quite know; if I better understood the relationship between `D` and `Derivative`, I think I would know why your version didn't work.

Comment: I've Accepted this Answer because it did work, but I think I'm going to post another question about why 'D' couldn't do the recursion.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I posted a follow up:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96853/strange-failure-of-series-and-derivative