# Strange failure of Series and Derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, pattern-matching, series-expansion

I just spend three hours and posted two Questions trying to figure something out, and it turned out all the confusion was caused by this mysterious quirk.  I want to expand g[x,v] in v at v=0, using this relation to convert the derivative wrt v into derivatives wrt x:

$$\frac{dg[x,v]}{dv}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^{2}g}{dx^{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dg}{dx}\right)^{2}$$

When I use the following `Derivative` definition, `Series` does not perform the conversion and leaves the result in terms of derivative wrt $v$:

```
Derivative[q_, Except[0, n_]][g][x, v] :=  D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}, {v, n - 1}]/2;
Series[g[x, v], {v, 0, 4}]
```

$g(x,0)+v g^{(0,1)}(x,0)+\frac{1}{2} v^2
   g^{(0,2)}(x,0)+\frac{1}{6} v^3
   g^{(0,3)}(x,0)+\frac{1}{24} v^4
   g^{(0,4)}(x,0)+O\left(v^5\right)$

But if I perform the binomial expansion of the derivative of $g'^2$ by hand and use the following `Derivative` definition instead, `Series` works perfectly:

```
Derivative[m_, Except[0, n_]][t][x_, v_] := ( Derivative[2 + m, n - 1][t][x, v] + Sum[Binomial[n - 1, k] Binomial[m, j]*Derivative[m - j + 1, n - 1 - k][t][x, v]*Derivative[j + 1, k][t][x, v], {k, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, m}])/2;
Series[t[x, v], {v, 0, 2}]
```

$t(x,0)+\frac{1}{2}v\left(t^{(1,0)}(x,0)^2+t^{(2,0)}(x,0)\right)+\frac{1}{8} v^2 \left(4 t^{(2,0)}(x,0)t^{(1,0)}(x,0)^2+4t^{(3,0)}(x,0) t^{(1,0)}(x,0)+2t^{(2,0)}(x,0)^2+t^{(4,0)}(x,0)\right)+O\left(v^3\right)$

What gives?  What design quirk is making MMa not able to calculate and substitute that derivative?  I would like to **NOT** spend this much time fixing this problem again!    :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post a possible explanation later, but here's how to make it work: replace `v` with `v_`, change the point about which you are expanding by a variable, and then replacing that variable with `0` later:

```
Derivative[q_, Except[0, n_]][g][x, v_] :=  D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}, {v, n - 1}]/2;
Series[g[x, v], {v, a, 2}] /. a -> 0
```

This makes it so that `Series` will evaluate derivatives about a symbolic point `a`, and then the rule that you've created will evaluate with `a` in place of `v` (which is why I replaced `v` with the pattern `v_`). It seems like the problem with `Series` in the original case is that there's no intermediate evaluation where `g[x, v]` and derivatives appears: it jumps immediately to `g[x, 0]` and derivatives. Consider:

```
Trace[Series[g[x, v], {v, 0, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks.  I kinda suspected it was something like that, but I couldn't figure out a way to hack around such a problem even to test the theory.  This seems like a genuine MMa design "quirk" if we're not ready to use such strong words as "bug".

Comment: @JerryGuern. Could be, but if you actually peek under the hood at how the "data structure" of `Series` is defined, things make a little more sense (try to `FullForm` the result of a `Series` and you'll see what I mean). In any case, the order in which and the method by which things are evaluated will be at times "quirky" in whatever language you use. In this case, I imagine `Series` does some pattern matching first, then just puts the matched quantities directly into the "data structure".

Comment: Yes, that's a fair point.  And thanks for the intro to FullForm, which does shed some light on the problem.  I guess what I'm really looking for is insight into those quirks so that I can craft work-arounds for them without wasting hours.  Even the fellow who gave me the binomial expansion solution that worked didn't know why it worked when my approach didn't.  That was frustrating, to put it mildly.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is the way [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html) works, as it (effectively) represents the derivative of a pure function with regards to its parameters, based purely on position. In order to make this work, you can return a pure function, using `Evaluate` to pre-evaluate the derivative, like so:

```
Derivative[q_, Except[0, n_]][g] := Function[{x, v},
     Evaluate[
      D[(D[g[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[g[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}, {v, n - 1}]/2]];
```

Now `Series[g[x, v], {v, 0, 2}]` yields
$$ g(x,0)+\frac{1}{2} v \left(g^{(1,0)}(x,0)^2+g^{(2,0)}(x,0)\right)+\frac{1}{8} v^2 \left(4
   g^{(2,0)}(x,0) g^{(1,0)}(x,0)^2+4 g^{(3,0)}(x,0) g^{(1,0)}(x,0)+2
   g^{(2,0)}(x,0)^2+g^{(4,0)}(x,0)\right)+O\left(v^3\right) $$