# Good coding for a sequence of derivatives

Tags: performance-tuning, coding-style, timing

People on this site keep telling me that good MMa practice avoids the use of loops.

The code below calculates the same `Table` of derivatives two different ways, and the one with the `Do` loops is much faster.  I think the first, slower version is calculating the nth derivative from scratch without using the (n-1)th derivative as a starting point.

```
Derivative[q_, 1][y][x, v] = D[(D[y[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[y[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}]/2;
ord = 9;
Print[Timing[dgdv1 = Table[D[y[x, v], {v, i}], {i, 0, ord - 1}];]];
dgdv2 = Flatten[{y[x, v], Table[0, {i, 2, ord}]}];
Print[Timing[Do[dgdv2[[i]] = D[dgdv2[[i - 1]], v], {i, 2, ord}];]];
```

(*{3.931225,Null}

{2.449216,Null}
*)

So how can one efficiently calculate the first several derivatives of g[x,v] wrt v without using a loop?
Bonus Question:  Is there some even faster way to do this calculation?

**OP's EDIT**:  Some commentors below were confused by the first line of my code, in which I define a derivative relationship for g[x,v].  It's not really relevant to the computation speed issue this Question is about, but here is a [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningDerivatives.html) for people who want to learn about defining derivatives.

Comment: `Derivative` is already defined, you code has syntax problems.

Comment: With [NestList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) `NestList[D[#, x] &, y[x], 10]`

Comment: @rhermans  No, that's how you define derivatives for functions.

Comment: @Jerry Guern - I am pretty much lost on the first statement and how it affects subsequent statements. Could you kindly explain the first statement and how it affects `D[y[x,v], {v, i}]`?  Thank you

Comment: @JackLaVigne  The first line of my code implements a diff eq for $g[x,v]$ discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96853/strange-failure-of-series-and-derivative).  I didn't discuss the meaning of it here because it's outside the scope of the question about performance tuning.

Comment: I'm getting the impression from these Comments that some users don't know about defining special derivatives of functions.  Here is a [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningDerivatives.html).

Comment: @Jerry Guern - Thank you for the link. I for one was unaware about the the representation of derivatives in Mathematica. I think I am learning faster than I am forgetting on Stack Exchange but the derivative is approaching zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ord = 9;

Timing[d1 = Table[D[y[x, v], {v, i}], {i, 0, ord - 1}];][[1]]

(*  2.06537  *)
```

Rather than using [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), mapping onto a [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html) is often more efficient

```
Timing[
  d12 = D[y[x, v], {v, #}] & /@
     Range[0, ord - 1];][[1]]

(*  2.03747  *)
```

For a fair timing comparison, the initialization of the array should be included in the timing

```
Timing[
  d2 = Flatten[{y[x, v], Table[0, {i, 2, ord}]}];
  Do[d2[[i]] = D[d2[[i - 1]], v],
   {i, 2, ord}];][[1]]

(*  1.70694  *)
```

With symbolic operations it can sometimes be faster to [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) intermediate steps

```
d22 = Flatten[{y[x, v], Table[0, {i, 2, ord}]}];
Timing[
  Do[d22[[i]] = Simplify[D[d22[[i - 1]], v]],
    {i, 2, ord}];][[1]]

(*  0.307888  *)
```

However, for this type of problem [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) is faster (and "more Mathematica-like")

```
Timing[d3 = NestList[D[#, v] &, y[x, v], ord - 1];][[1]]

(*  1.58817  *)
```

Again using `Simplify`

```
Timing[d32 = NestList[Simplify[D[#, v]] &, y[x, v], ord - 1];][[1]]

(*  0.060246  *)
```

Verifying that all approaches return the same results

```
d1 == d12 == d2 == d22 == d3 == d32 // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: This was great, thanks.  I posted a comparison of the two methods in an Answer below.  With `Expand` performed on each derivative, the two methods had similar Timing.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP: This is not an Answer, just an extended comment on @BobHanlon's Answer above, which I Accepted.  I tried both methods on a longer run and included the `Table` initialization in the `Timing`, and I found that the methods were very similar in kernel time, but which was faster varied in different runs:

```
Derivative[q_, 1][y][x, v] = 
  D[(D[y[x, v], {x, 2}] + D[y[x, v], x]^2), {x, q}]/2;
ord = 16;
Print[Timing[
   dgdv2 = Flatten[{y[x, v], Table[0, {i, 2, ord}]}];
   Do[dgdv2[[i]] = Expand[D[dgdv2[[i - 1]], v]], {i, 2, ord}];]];
Print[Timing[dgdv3 = NestList[Expand[D[#, v]] &, y[x, v], ord - 1];]];
dgdv2 == dgdv3
```

Output from 3 runs:

(*
{25.584164,Null}
{25.006960,Null}
True

{24.226955,Null}
{24.336156,Null}
True

{24.211355,Null}
{24.601358,Null}
True
*)

Comment: Your use of `Print` is unnecessary if you don't suppress the output with the final semi-colon. `expr` will give the same output as `Print[expr];`